# Делегирование событий jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, почему не срабатывает делегирование?
Имеется блок с классом .team-item. Надо, чтобы при наведении на любую его часть текст менял цвет. Текст имеет класс .name-description. Файл js и jq подключены в конце body. В файле js написано так:

```
$('.team-item').on('hover', function() {
    $('.name-description').css("color", "#00e0d0");
});
```

Comment: добавь html Разметку. И допиши: что и куда ты тут делегируешь

Comment: не вижу делегирования в вашем коде.

Comment: Тут `.team-item` ничего не делегирует. Делегирование достигается путём передачи второго аргумента с CSS-селектором, которые и будут целью обработчика. А во главе угла (`$(...).on(...);`) должен быть родитель.

Comment: "Файл js и jq подключены в конце body." - в каком порядке?

Answer (score 1):

Читайте док. http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Решение 1:

```js
$('.team-item').hover( 
    function() {
      $('.name-description').css("color", "#00e0d0");
    }, 
    function(){
      $('.name-description').css("color", "inherit");
    }        
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="team-item">Hover it</div>
  
  <div class="name-description">Change color</div>
```

[Решение 2 jsbin:](http://jsbin.com/neyerew/edit?html,js,output)

```
$('.team-item').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $('.name-description').css("color", "#00e0d0");
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $('.name-description').css("color", "inherit");
    } 
});
```

Comment: _это невозможно_ - что именно **это**?

Comment: а почему решение 2 на jsbin, а не так же в сниппете?

Comment: @Grundy, хочу так!

Comment: В идеале, лучше пользоваться встроенным сниппетом, чтобы случись что с jsbin, пример решения не пропал. Ну и для консистентности, чтобы все было однообразно

Comment: @Grundy, а я люблю разнообразие, но учту на будущее Ваш совет!